# Getting ORA-00904 invalid identifier error on column that exists

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I have an Oracle query here:

```
UPDATE metadata.bp_assets
SET (ASSET_RID, CONTAINER_RID, ASSET_NAME, ASSET_SUBTYPE) = (
    select  max(METADATA.BP_ASSET_TO_CLUSTER.ASSET_RID),    
            max(AD.CONTAINER_RID),
            max(AD.NAME_XMETA),
            max(AD.SUBTYPE_XMETA)            
        from asclmodel_datafield AD
        join metadata.bp_asset_to_cluster ATC
        on AD.xmeta_repos_object_id_xmeta = ATC.asset_rid
        WHERE METADATA.BP_ASSET_TO_CLUSTER.ASSET_RID = XMETA_REPOS_OBJECT_ID_XMETA
)
```

and on the WHERE clause at the bottom I get the ORA-00904 invalid identifier error. I have even tried just running the select part without the UPDATE and SET and still no luck. If I try to just query the column itself it works just fine. Not having any luck with any other SO answers.

EDIT: Sorry forgot to mention that the error is on the METADATA.BP_ASSET_TO_CLUSTER.ASSET_RID column.

Comment: which column is getting the 904?

Comment: agreed, can you edit your question and post exact ORA-00904 error?

Comment: Suspect the problem is that you've aliased metadata.bp_asset_to_cluster as ATC in your JOIN, but reference it by name in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question now. I forgot to mention the column at first.

Comment: please try what OTTA is suggesting above, if still experiencing same issue, please post the DDL /field structure of your METADATA.BP_ASSET_TO_CLUSTER table

Comment: Removing the aliases worked. Thank you very much @OTTA

Comment: My pleasure :-)